# To find active directory user attributes (username, host name and logon time) PHP/LDAP?

Tags: php, ldap

I am able to connect to LDAP (test server ldap.forumsys.com) but the code to get user attributes does not work. Can you please help me out?

```
/**
 * Get a list of users from Active Directory.
 */
$ldap_password = 'PASSWORD';
$ldap_username = 'USERNAME@DOMAIN';
$ldap_connection = ldap_connect(HOSTNAME);
if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
    // Uh-oh, something is wrong...
}

// We have to set this option for the version of Active Directory we are using.
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

if (TRUE === ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){
    $ldap_base_dn = 'DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX';
    $search_filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=*))';
    $attributes = array();
    $attributes[] = 'givenname';
    $attributes[] = 'mail';
    $attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
    $attributes[] = 'sn';
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);
    if (FALSE !== $result){
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
        for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
            if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['sn'][0]) &&
                 'Shop' !== $entries[$x]['sn'][0] &&
                 'Account' !== $entries[$x]['sn'][0]){
                $ad_users[strtoupper(trim($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]))] = array('email' => strtolower(trim($entries[$x]['mail'][0])),'first_name' => trim($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]),'last_name' => trim($entries[$x]['sn'][0]));
            }
        }
    }
    ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); // Clean up after ourselves.
}

$message .= "Retrieved ". count($ad_users) ." Active Directory users\n";
```

Comment: "Does not work" is too vague to help you. Got any specifics about how it doesn't work?

Comment: the result set is empty!!! i cannot find any results or any errors in the code

Comment: anyone help me out with this ? thanks

Comment: The best way to debug in such cases is to connect to your LDAP server using a an LDAP browser , say Apache Dir Studio , and run the same query/filter.

Comment: You probably want your filter to be: `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=*))`. Also, you could be hitting a limit with your search and it just fails. As it's best practice to limit AD query results on DCs to 1000 results per page. Your current query pulls every possible user, which could be a lot of results.

Comment: I tried But results are empty $search_filter = '(&(ObjectCatergory=person)(ObjectClass=User)(samaccountname=*))'; DC=XX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX

Comment: Anyone Please help me out thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: hi please help me out

Comment: I am also working on the same, @darshan Did u find any solution? any help. I need only "generic user account attributes" from php ldap server.